# "Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…". " Error with D3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, d3.js

I'm importing some data from Quandl's API to make a chart of brent oil prices over the years. I'm serving the data from a HTTP-request made with Angular. Somehow the data being served is not being read as numbers, since i get the following error:

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…".

```
app.service('oilService', function($http) {
  delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
  this.getData = function() {
  var URL = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/CHRIS/ICE_B1.json";
  return $http({
     method: 'GET',
     url: URL
  })
 }
})

.directive('oilGraph', function() {
 return {
  scope: {},
  controller: function(oilService) {
  var width = 200;
  var height = 100;

  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%y-%m-%d");

  var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

  var valueline = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.settle); });
  var svg = d3.select("#oilgraph").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

  oilService.getData()
  .then(function(data) {

      var mapped_data = data.data.data.map(function(d) {
        return {
          date: parseTime(d[0]),
          settle: d[4]
        };
      })

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.settle; })]);

      svg.append("path")
          .data([mapped_data])
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", valueline);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      svg.append("g")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    })
   })
  }
 }
})
```

Comment: Share your JSON (just a few objects)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado `{
  "date": null,
  "settle": 47.42
}`

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Well, the date should've been there. Not sure why it's not parsing correctly. It's the same for all the other objects, "settle"-data is retrieved correctly, but all the date-values are null.

Comment: `null` doesn't help us to see the date objects at all. The best idea is creating a plunker/codepen/fiddle/whatever **with your json**, even if it doesn't work properly, so we can investigate what's happening.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Could you be more specific? The raw JSON-data from the API or the objects in mapped_data?

Comment: The raw json data.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Assuming you have JSONView in your browser, you can check it out here: https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/CHRIS/ICE_B1.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is just a wrong specifier. Since your dates have the century...

```
"2017-06-16"
```

... you should use `%Y` instead of `%y`. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format):

> %Y - year with century as a decimal number.

Thus, this should be your specifier:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
```

Besides that, you have to use `mapped_data` in the scales, not `data`.

Here is your code with that changes:

```js
var width = 500;
var height = 200;

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.settle);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

d3.json("https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/CHRIS/ICE_B1.json", function(data) {

  var mapped_data = data.data.map(function(d) {
    return {
      date: parseTime(d[0]),
      settle: d[4]
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(mapped_data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(mapped_data, function(d) {
    return d.settle;
  })]);

  svg.append("path")
    .data([mapped_data])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

})
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What you mean by *"no line showing"*? Are you clicking "Run code snippet"? I'm definitely seeing the line, I'm looking at it right now.

Comment: Hmm, weird! I see it in your snippet, but not my own running instance.

Comment: In that case, you have other problem somewhere else. This one was fixed.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i can see, in your code at

```
       svg.append("path")
      .data([mapped_data])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);`
```

**.attr("d", valueline);**, "valueline is giving you nan", either you want to use property of value line. i.e x and y property of it you setting it in above of your code.

Comment: You're right. After i changed it to: `.attr("d", valueline.y('m'));` the error has disappeared, although the chart is still empty.

Comment: This answer is wrong: `valueline` is just the line generator. Doing `.attr("d", valueline)`, as OP did, is what everybody does in D3.

Comment: my friend, you declared value line as variable which you using it while createing svg path element. See this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN.

Comment: I have no idea of what you're talking about. Look at the last line in this code, by the creator of D3: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245. It is `.attr("d", line)`, just as OP did. Again, there is nothing wrong with that piece of code.